# Unable to detect wifi network in Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: wireless

I tried following the steps mentioned in this link:
[make: *** [modules] Error 2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042399/make-modules-error-2)

When I am typing this command:

```
sudo modprobe rtl8723de
```

I am getting the error:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module rtl8723de not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-34-generic
```

Previously I tried the command `rm /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` as it was giving bad option error.

Steps as follows:

```
$ sudo rm -r rtl8723de*
rm: cannot remove 'rtl8723de*': No such file or directory

$ sudo apt update && sudo apt -y install git
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
done

$ cd rtlwifi_new
$ make
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-34-generic'

$ sudo make install
make -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-34-generic/build M=/home/shubham/rtlwifi_new modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-34-generic'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 15 modules
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-34-generic'
Making backups
Install rtlwifi SUCCESS

$ sudo modprobe rtl8723de
modprobe: FATAL: Module rtl8723de not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-34-generic
```

Comment: Did each and every step leading up to 'modprobe' complete without error?

Comment: updated output of each step

Comment: Did you clone a new fresh copy just now? Please see my edit at the question you linked and follow that procedure. The reason that I think you are working on an old copy of the git is that your process builds 15 modules. I just ran make clean, git pull and make and I get *19* modules. Presumably, rtl8723de is one of the missing modules.

Comment: again I am getting only 15 modules

Comment: Please run the entire process at my edit and show us the complete output here: http://paste.ubuntu.com Give us the link.

Comment: Here it is: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/JFXJrPK7Hh/

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
sudo rm -rf rtlwifi_new
git clone -b extended https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install 
sudo modprobe rtl8723de
```

Post any errors, please.

We cloned the 'extended' branch of the git. Mr. Finger currently maintains *nine* branches for this driver suite. He adds and deletes branches from time to time. Therefore, not every answer posted on every forum will be valid forever.

Comment: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8723de': Required key not available

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4BmYZsYWpT/

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules Please disable secure boot and your wireless should be working.

Comment: It's 4:00 am here. I will sleep now and will update you tomorrow. Thanks for the help.